# Creating a test report with Azure Pipelines and Coverlet does not create the coverage.opencover.xml file

Tags: azure-pipelines, codecov, coverlet

Here is my solution structure:

```
.
├── Application
├── Application.Core
├── Application.Domain
└── Application.UnitTests -> HAS codecov 1.9.0 NuGet package installed
```

The build script works otherwise fine, but I'm unable to get it to create the coverlet results as `coverage.opencover.xml` format at the root folder.

My azure-pipelines.yml:

```
trigger:
  - master

pool:
  vmImage: "vs2017-win2016"

variables:
  solution: "**/*.sln"
  buildPlatform: "Any CPU"
  buildConfiguration: "Release"

steps:
  - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
    displayName: "Building **/*.csproj..."
    inputs:
      command: build
      projects: "**/*.csproj"
      arguments: "--configuration Release"

  - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
    condition: succeededOrFailed()
    displayName: Testing **/*.UnitTests/*.csproj
    inputs:
      command: test
      projects: |
        **/*.UnitTests/*.csproj
      arguments: '--configuration $(buildConfiguration) /p:CollectCoverage=true /p:CoverletOutput=$(Agent.BuildDirectory)\coverage /p:CoverletOutputFormat=opencover /p:Exclude="[*Tests]*"'
      nobuild: true

  - task: PublishTestResults@2
    condition: succeededOrFailed()
    inputs:
      testRunner: VSTest
      testResultsFiles: "**/*.opencover.xml"
  - powershell: .\codecov.ps1 -token $(CODECOV_TOKEN) $(Agent.BuildDirectory)\coverage.opencover.xml
    displayName: Upload to CodeCov.io
```

As a result, I get the following output for the `Testing **/*.UnitTests/*.csproj` task:

> Starting: Testing **/*.UnitTests/*.csproj
>   ============================================================================== Task         : .NET Core Description  : Build, test, package, or
>   publish a dotnet application, or run a custom dotnet command Version
>   : 2.162.0 Author       : Microsoft Corporation Help         :
>   https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/build/dotnet-core-cli
>   ============================================================================== C:\windows\system32\chcp.com 65001 Active code page: 65001 "C:\Program
>   Files\dotnet\dotnet.exe" test
>   d:\a\1\s\BlazorApp.UnitTests\BlazorApp.UnitTests.csproj
>   --logger trx --results-directory d:\a_temp --configuration Release /p:CollectCoverage=true /p:CoverletOutput=d:\a\1\coverage
>   /p:CoverletOutputFormat=opencover /p:Exclude=[*Tests]* Test run for
>   d:\a\1\s\BlazorApp.UnitTests\bin\Release\netcoreapp3.1\BlazorApp.UnitTests.dll(.NETCoreApp,Version=v3.1)
>   Microsoft (R) Test Execution Command Line Tool Version 16.3.0
>   Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.
>
> Starting test execution, please wait...
>
> A total of 1 test files matched the specified pattern. Results File:
>   d:\a_temp\VssAdministrator_fv-az74_2019-12-25_11_32_03.trx
>
> Test Run Successful. Total tests: 1
>        Passed: 1  Total time: 1.5842 Seconds

Problem is that no `coverage.opencover.xml` file is created even the `yml` parameters define the coverlet settings which should be executed. The `codecov.ps1` PowerShell script works if it can find the test result file which is now missing.

Answer (score 3):

Basically, it seems that the default `DotNetCoreCLI@2` task will add `--results-directory d:\a_temp` parameter to the test command unless otherwise defined. This seems to prevent coverlet from running.

I changed the output filetype to `cobertura` for compatibility and added the following definition to the task: `publishTestResults: false` which seems to have solved my issue.

```
  - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
    condition: succeededOrFailed()
    displayName: Testing **/*.UnitTests/*.csproj
    inputs:
      command: test
      projects: |
        **/*.UnitTests/*.csproj
      arguments: '--configuration $(buildConfiguration) /p:CollectCoverage=true /p:CoverletOutput=$(Agent.BuildDirectory)\coverage /p:CoverletOutputFormat=cobertura /p:Exclude="[*Tests]*"'
      nobuild: true
      publishTestResults: false
```

Comment: I'm using coverlet in similar way but had the same problem when I changed to a windows VM (from unbuntu). My coverage report in Azure Devops disappeared simply cos I changed VM type.  I set `nobuild: true` and `publishTestResults: false` and it came back. Thanks for this answer!

Answer (score 1):

You can also ensure that your unit test project contains NuGet references for coverlet.msbuild and OpenCover. I think coverlet.msbuild alone should be fine.